# How to do replace dynamic query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

How can i optimize following sql query,any way to replace dynamic query  to?...thanks

```
 DECLARE @NUM INT,
         @NAME VARCHAR(20),
         @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET  @SQL='SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE A'
IF(@NUM<>0)
BEGIN
SET @SQL=@SQL+'JOIN DEPARTMENT B ON A.N_ID=B.N_ID'
END
IF @NAME IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SET @SQL=@SQL+'WHERE ENAME like '''+'%'+@NAME+'%'+''''
END EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of the number of returned columns, this query should be about right. It may need some tweaking for your exact table structure.

I don't know if this is the optimal solution, it depends if you have an index on [Ename].

```
DECLARE @num INT
        ,@name VARCHAR(20)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    EMPLOYEE A
        LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT B 
            ON 
            A.N_ID = B.N_ID
            AND
            @num <> 0
WHERE
    EName LIKE '%'+ISNULL(@name,EName)+'%'
```

UPDATE: (Based on Comments)
If you are allowing users to pass SQL Code as Parameters, please read-up on the following link:
[SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thanks pacreely, if i've passed query string using parameter(@QRY),then how can achieve?  
                      `DECLARE @NUM INT,
       @NAME VARCHAR(20),
             @QRY VARCHAR(MAX)='AND DEPT IN (5,6)'
       @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
  SET  @SQL='SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE A'
 IF(@NUM<>0)
 BEGIN
 SET @SQL=@SQL+'JOIN DEPARTMENT B ON A.N_ID=B.N_ID'
 END
 IF @NAME IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
 SET @SQL=@SQL+'WHERE ENAME like '''+'%'+@NAME+'%'+''''
 END 
    IF @QRY IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 
    SET @SQL=@SQL+@QRY
    END EXEC(@SQL)`

Comment: The @QRY represents a piece of SQL code and not discrete values, the only way to include it is with Dynamic SQL. One option you have is to load the values 5 & 6 into another table then perform an Inner Join to that table.

Comment: Thanks  pacreely, @QRY is just a parameter for end user, they will give any piece of SQL code like a dept.

Comment: If it's Code then you can't get away from Dynamic SQL. Your only possible solution is to change how the User interacts with the system.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the dynamic part... your IF statements will decide which statement is executed

```
DECLARE @NUM INT, @NAME VARCHAR(20)

IF(@NUM<>0)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE A JOIN DEPARTMENT B ON A.N_ID=B.N_ID
END
IF @NAME IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE A WHERE ENAME like '%'+@NAME+'%'
END
```

Naturally this is executed in order. So if `@NUM <> 0` **and** `@NAME IS NOT NULL`, only the first IF will be executed.

Comment: Thanks scsimon,your query only suitable for simple dynamic part only, if I've lot of lines within dynamic part then how can achieve???

Comment: You'll have to elaborate @Thangadurai  and provide a better example. Most likely you can add another IF and ELSE clause